# PHP - Injecting the same instance (service) in multiple layers

Tags: php, service, dependency-injection

I need to have some instances (services like an event dispatcher...) to be accessible in most of my program.

All of my classes extends a Container class that allows for easy dependency injection with the magic methods `__set` and `__get` like so:

```
class Container {
    private $_map = array();

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->_map[$name];
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->_map[$name] = $value;
    }
}

class Dependent extends Container {

     public function doStuff() {
          $this->dependency->doThing('some text');
     }

}

class Dependency {

    public function doThing($txt) {
        echo $txt;
    }

}


$dependent = new Dependent;
$dependent->dependency = new Dependency; // Injecting dependency

$denpendent->doStuff(); // Prints out "some text"
```

So in my system (MVC application) I have a front controller that instantiates all the services I need in all my classes, and then it injects them in the other classes, and so on:

```
FrontController
    injects services to: Controller
         injects services to: View and Model
             ...
```

So it becomes confusing when I have a class that injects a dependency in another class that itself injects this dependency in another class.

Should I still use this system? It allows for easy testing and is easy to use, but it becomes hard to manage when I have to inject the same dependency in several layers of instances.

Should I use a service locator based on the container? Or should I do something else completly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not really what I'd call DI. What's the point of the Container class you have. Why are you extending it? In a system with a DI component, the container sits in the bowels of the system and manages the instantiation of all (nearly) all dependencies. You rarely have to write `new X`. PS: Service locator is considered to be an anti-pattern

Comment: The container allows to inject dependencies with a simple syntax and also allows for easy testing, you can change the dependency easily by just `$dep->dependency = new X`. So when I want to inject a dependency in an object I have to use this syntax. That's why all my classes extends from the `Container` class, it allows them to use this syntax to inject dependencies without having to pass them in the constructor or having to use any special syntax to inject a dependency.